# Bootstrap tooltip positioned on a child element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a Bootstrap tooltip like this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/opvLsjy9/)):

[image]

```
<span title='Description about this' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Some text here
</span>
```

I want it to be aligned to the icon inside it, but I want to achieve this without moving the popover onto the icon element, because the semantics of the tooltip information belongs to the span.

This is how it should look, but I don't want to use this markup:

[image]

```
<span>
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" title='Description about this' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top"></i>
   Some text here
</span>
```

Comment: you could use `.tooltip {margin-left: -50px;}`, calculating the actual 1/2 width of the span either in javascript or using some css trick...

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the bootstrap tooltip class with `!important`.

**Html**:

```
<div class="content">
    <span title='Description about this' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Some text here
    </span>
</div>
```

**Style**:

```
body{
  margin: 4em;
}
[title]{
  cursor: help;
}

.content .tooltip{
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cLmn9o1n/

Comment: not really what I want, because the child or parent can have padding, margins, also will not work with data-placement-right for example.